# Java: compound assignment and expression based type promotion

Tags: java, types, promotions

In the three bitwise left shift code fragments below, it's interesting that examples #2 and #3 are treated differently by Java.  In the last example (#3), why does Java decide not to upgrade the compound assignment statement to an int?

Does the answer have something to do with Java doing things "inline".  Thanks a lot for any comments.

```
byte b = -128;

// Eg #1.  Expression is promoted to an int, and its expected value for an int is -256.
System.out.println(b << 1);

b = -128;
// Eg #2.  Must use a cast, otherwise a compilation error will occur.  
// Value is 0, as to be expected for a byte.
System.out.println(b = (byte)(b << 1));

b = -128;
// Eg #3.  Not only is no cast required, but the statement isn't "upgraded" to an int.
// Its value is 0, as to be expected for a byte.
System.out.println(b <<= 1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compound assignment operators e.g `+=` and `-=` and `<<=`, etc have a implicit type cast in their operation.

In other words.

```
byte x = 1;
x <<= 4;
```

is equal to:

```
byte x = 1;
x = (byte)(x << 4);
```

when compiled.

The left-shift operation still promotes the variables appropriately (in the case of `byte` to an `int`) but the compound assignment operator casts it for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
println b <<= 1
```

is the same as

```
b = (byte) (b << 1)
println b
```

So this implies the cast to `byte` as well as your second example.