# Compilation error in a program of java

Tags: java, expression

Consider the below code:

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer i = 9;
        char c = 'a';
        c = c*i; \\ compilation error
        c *= i;
        System.out.println(c);  
    }

}
```

My doubt is `c = c*i` is giving compilation error but why not `c *= i` though I know that both the expressions are equivalent.

Comment: `c*i` is `int` when `c *= i` is `char`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functionally, the expressions `c = c * i;` and `c *= i;` are indeed equivalent - they should do the same thing.

However, you are doing calculations with different types here (`int` and `char`) and the Java programming language has rules about what conversions between the types are done automatically (without a cast) and when you have to explicitly do a cast.

These conversions are described in detail in [chapter 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html) of the Java Language Specification.

The multiplication of a `char` and an `int` in `c * i` results in a value of type `int`, as described in [5.6.2 Binary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2). You then try to assign that to a `char`, which is a [narrowing primitive conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) which cannot be done without a cast.

[15.26.2 Compound Assignment Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) explains operators such as `*=`. This paragraph explains:

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

Note that a cast to the type of the left-hand variable is implicitly done. So if you do `c *= i;`, this is equivalent to:

```
c = (char)(c * i);
```

The cast from `int` to `char` is done implicitly.

Answer (score 2):

THe two expressions are **not** equivalent.

[JLS 15.26.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) explains it :

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.

Therefore :

```
c *= i;
```

is equivalent to

```
c = (char) (c * i);
```

which is not the same as

```
c = c * i;
```

Answer (score 0):

> c = c*i; // compilation error

The reason you are getting compilation error is because `c*i` will be evaluated as integer and you are trying to assign it to a character.
Where as `c*=i` is evaluated as character hence a valid assignment.

There is fundamental difference between `c*i` and `c*=i`.
`c*i` is always `integer` as `i` is `integer`, whereas `c*=i` is `c=(char)c*i`

Comment: But both the expressions are equivalent right...then why one is evaluated as char and another as int

Comment: I have updated my answer highlighting difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

case -1 : `c = c*i;`

Here you will get a compilation error because the result of `c * i` will be an `int` which cannot be assigned to a char.

case-2 : `c *= i;`

Now this case is a little interesting. Looking at the byte code :

```
   9: iload_2  // load c as an integer --> here is the critical section
   10: aload_1  // load reference i
   14: imul     // multiply 1 and 2
   15: i2c       // convert integer back to char
   16: istore_2  // store value in c

  LocalVariableTable:
    Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
        0      25     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
        6      19     1     i   Ljava/lang/Integer;
        9      16     2     c   C
```

Comment: @Leo - Check *Jesper's / Erans* answer. Look at JLS and come back to see the byte code here :)

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, compound assignment operators (`+=`, `-=`, etc) have a implicit type cast in their operation.

Hence when you use `c *= i;`, the compound assignment operator promotes the variables appropriately (in the case of `char` to an `int`), and automatically casts the result back to `char`.

See: [Java: compound assignment and expression based type promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859237/java-compound-assignment-and-expression-based-type-promotion)

Answer (score 0):

```js
(c *= i)==(c = (char) (c * i));

Both Are Same Result Print But (c = c*i)  invalid Sytex i is Integer anc c char :
here need a possibaly loss precision integar and char.
you need 

c = (char) (c * i)
```